# How to deploy data source of type OData to scratch org

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, odata

I'm trying to deploy an external data source of type 'OData' to my scratch org. The scratch org is an 'Enterprise' type. I get the following error:

> This org does not have the appropriate permissions to use the 'OData'
>   data provider

From the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=platform_connect_add_external_data_source.htm&type=5) I learned that the feature is:

> Available in: Developer Edition
>
> Available for an extra cost in: Enterprise, Performance, and Unlimited Editions

The data source is retrieved from one of our sandboxes which is an 'Unlimited Edition'.

How can I enable my scratch org to create an external data source of 'OData' type?

Answer (score 2):

When creating the scratch Org, make sure that `edition` in definition file is assigned to `developer`. The Developer Edition will allow us to use 'OData'.

```
{
  "orgName": "ABC",
  "edition": "developer",
  "features": [],
  "settings": {
      "orgPreferenceSettings": {
          "s1DesktopEnabled": true,
      },
      "caseSettings": {
          "systemUserEmail": "support@abc.com"
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there another option if you require Enterprise edition for other settings?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the PlatformConnect feature to your project-scratch-def.json in an Enterprise Edition Scratch Org https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file_config_values.htm#so_platformconnect

```
{
  "orgName": "ABC",
  "edition": "Enterprise",
  "features": [PlatformConnect:5],
  "settings": {
      "orgPreferenceSettings": {
          "s1DesktopEnabled": true,
      },
      "caseSettings": {
          "systemUserEmail": "support@abc.com"
      }
  }
}
```